# Converting windows excel vba code compatible with mac

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following 4 codes working perfectly on a Windows pc.
The problem is, it is not working correctly when used on a Mac pc.

I have no experience coding vba on mac platform and no mac pc as well to debug the codes.

A little help converting or testing the following codes on a mac pc will be very much appreciated.

**Code 1:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "^1", "HideSheets"
End Sub
```

**Code 2:**

```
Sub HideSheets()
Dim myPassword As String
myPassword = "PASSWORD" ' Set password here
Password = InputBox("Enter Password")
If Password = "" Then Exit Sub ' Exit if no password iputted

' Incorrect password
If Password <> myPassword Then
MsgBox Title:="Warning", prompt:="Incorrect Password"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next

' Correct password
If Worksheets("Services").Visible = True Then
Worksheets("Services").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
ActiveSheet.Protect myPassword, True, True
Else
Worksheets("Services").Visible = True
ActiveSheet.Unprotect myPassword
End If
End Sub
```

**Code 3:**

```
Private Sub Auto_Close()
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Services").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden ' Hide worksheets
ActiveSheet.Protect "PASSWORD"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

**Code 4:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rRng As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B17:B38")

If Not Application.Intersect(rRng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False

With ActiveSheet
.Unprotect "PASSWORD"
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
Select Case rCell.Value
Case "CASE 1", "CASE 2", "CASE 3", "CASE 4", "CASE 5"
rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1
rCell.Offset(0, 2).Locked = True
Case Else
rCell.Offset(0, 2).Locked = False
End Select
Next rCell
End With

ActiveSheet.Protect "PASSWORD"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

I can use the below subroutine to check if a user is using a mac or a windows pc. But since I don't have a mac pc, I can't debug if my codes are working correctly.

```
Sub WINorMAC_1()
If Mac Then
'Call the Mac version of the 4 codes above
Else
'Call each of the 4 codes above
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is a question for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).